# How to get list objects with an id that is not the primary key of an object in firebase DataRealtime

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I need to get message objects with an id that is not the primary key of an object in firebase DataRealtime. How can I do this?

This is for a chat app to learn firebase. I can get all messages using info from [the docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write?authuser=0/).

But I don't know how to get messages with `userid=1`.

My firebase data:

```
message 
   -LVr5ctrnbRXtZ7lxcL1
        text: "Hello nice to meet you"
        time: 1547112680605
        userid: 2
  -LVr5msnECOEfsghjMZn
        text: "i'm here\nwho are u"
        time: 1547112721497
        userid: 1
  -LVrCX797YRZVg2qPBIS
        text: "hi\n"
        time: 1547114487906
        userid: 1
  -LVrNWDwE-jOPMzUX4zY
        text: "hahaa"
        time: 1547117401142
        userid: 3
  -LVunQcfAJW4yCYtPWzp
        text: "hoho"
        time: 1547174787733
        userid: 1
```

My current code:

```
   mFirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    mMessageDatabaseReference = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference().child("message/userid");
    Query queryget=mMessageDatabaseReference.equalTo(1);
    mChildEventListener = new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
            FriendlyMessage friendlyMessage=dataSnapshot.getValue(FriendlyMessage.class);
            mMessageAdapter.add(friendlyMessage);
        }
    queryget.addChildEventListener(mChildEventListener);
```

I would like to get a list of message that have `userid=1` but I only get `null`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your child reference is incorrect. In your case you should get all messages as objects and then sort it where userId = 1.

You can do this with:

```
mMessageDatabaseReference = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference().child("message");
Query queryget = mMessageDatabaseReference.orderBy("userid").equalTo(1);
```

Comment: many tks, it worked^^,so if i need userid=1 and userid=2 , how do it?

Comment: You will need to get data separately